Unable to create Nested JSON with json_array and json_objects using Oracle SQL
Trying to create JSON using ORACLE SQL. I'm able to create them individually but putting them together is not producing the output or produces errors out.  Any help on this will be highly appreciated.
Desired JSON output
{
  "Id": "f2701e23-267b-4334-b4f9-5776a49032ec",
  "arrList": [
    {
      "name": "Quantity",
      "value": "0"
    },
    {
      "name": "SupplierQty",
      "value": "0"
    },
    {
      "name": "Supplier",
      "value": "MK"
    }
  ],
  "item": "12345",
  "quantity": {
    "UnitCode": "EA",
    "value": 0
  }
}

SQL query
select item,id,
       json_object('id' VALUE ilv.id,
                   'arrList' VALUE JSON_ARRAY(
                         JSON_OBJECT('name' VALUE 'Quantity', 'value' VALUE ilv.Quantity),
                         JSON_OBJECT('name' VALUE 'SupplierQty',VALUE ilv.SupplierQty),
                         JSON_OBJECT('name' VALUE 'Supplier',VALUE ilv.Supplier)                         
                                    )   ,   
                    'item' VALUE ilv.item,  
                    'quantity' VALUE JSON_OBJECT('name' VALUE 'UnitCode', 'value' VALUE ilv.projqty)           
        )AS json_detail
  from 
(select '12345' item,
       12 projqty,
       0 Quantity,
       0 SupplierQty,
       'MK' Supplier,
       sys_guid() id
  from dual)ilv


The code you included gets error "ORA-02000: missing VALUE keyword". Some of your JSON_OBJECT clauses are missing the 'values' key name... with those added you get:
select item,id,
       json_object('id' VALUE ilv.id,
                   'arrList' VALUE JSON_ARRAY(
                         JSON_OBJECT('name' VALUE 'Quantity', 'value' VALUE ilv.Quantity),
                         JSON_OBJECT('name' VALUE 'SupplierQty', 'value' VALUE ilv.SupplierQty),
                         JSON_OBJECT('name' VALUE 'Supplier', 'value' VALUE ilv.Supplier)                         
                                    )   ,   
                    'item' VALUE ilv.item,  
                    'quantity' VALUE JSON_OBJECT('name' VALUE 'UnitCode', 'value' VALUE ilv.projqty)           
        )AS json_detail
  from 
(select '12345' item,
       12 projqty,
       0 Quantity,
       0 SupplierQty,
       'MK' Supplier,
       sys_guid() id
  from dual)ilv




ITEM
ID
JSON_DETAIL




12345
0x25D8890F0CB93E5DE063182BA8C063DE
{"id":"25D8890F0CBA3E5DE063182BA8C063DE","arrList":[{"name":"Quantity","value":0},{"name":"SupplierQty","value":0},{"name":"Supplier","value":"MK"}],"item":"12345","quantity":{"name":"UnitCode","value":12}}



fiddle
which prettified is:
{
   "id":"25D8890F0CBA3E5DE063182BA8C063DE",
   "arrList":[
      {
         "name":"Quantity",
         "value":0
      },
      {
         "name":"SupplierQty",
         "value":0
      },
      {
         "name":"Supplier",
         "value":"MK"
      }
   ],
   "item":"12345",
   "quantity":{
      "name":"UnitCode",
      "value":12
   }
}

Your example output end with
"quantity": {
    "UnitCode": "EA",
    "value": 0.0
}

but that doesn't match your sample data or code attempt; projqty is 12 not 0.0, and you don't have a column matching 'EA'.

Thanks @alex Poole, i see the mistakes. Gracias
